# Approximations inside Integals

Tags: integration

Generally speaking, approximating a function in a calculus problem with another function which looks similar (in some sense or another) is dangerous, since while the functions may look similar, a lot of their attributes are probably still be very different. For example, if you calculate the 4-th derivative of a function $f\left(x\right)$, in many cases it will be VERY different from the 4-th derivative of $g\left(x\right)$ which may look very similar to $f$.

Now, assume you have an integral of the following form:
$$I=\int_{y\in\mathcal{Y}}\delta\left(y-y_{0}\right)\left[\int_{x\in\mathcal{X}}f\left(x,y\right)dx\right]dy\quad ; \quad y_0\in\mathcal{Y}$$
Also assume that you cannot perform the integral over $x$ analytically, but the function $f\left(x,y\right)$ is adequately approximated (for $x\in\mathcal{X}$ and $y\in\mathcal{Y}$) by a function $g\left(x,y\right)$, over which you can integrate easily.

Is it legal (as an approximation) to replace $f\left(x,y\right)$ with $g\left(x,y\right)$ in this case? On what conditions?

Comment: If the integral of the difference between $f$ and $g$ is small compared to the integral of either $f$ or $g$, the approximation is good.

Comment: The given integral can already simplified by use of the delta function, so one gets $\int f(x,y_0) dx$. Probably a look in an integration table like Gradshteyn & Ryzhik helps. Otherwise one can compute the integral numerically in many cases (or use Mathematica).

Comment: If the 4th derivative of the integral has to be taken, if it is the derivative vs. x the derivative might be taken already below the integral --- well one has to make sure that the derived function is still integrable -- so basic math rules have to checked before really doing it.

Comment: I don't understand legal in this context. Obviously you don't mean in the law sense, so what do you mean?

Comment: This isn't really a physics question though, you'd likely get more information or a better answer on Mathematics stackexchange.